How to pause and resume Azure Synapse Link via automation?
Is there a way to pause and resume Azure Synapse Link via automation using Windows PowerShell or other technology?
I am trying to reduce the cost of running Synapse 24/7. Presently I have Aruze Synapse Link importing new and changed records from multiple Azure databases into a dedicated SQL database. I have figured out how to pause and resume the dedicated SQL database using Windows PowerShell. The Aruze Synapse Link continues to run even when the dedicated SQL database is paused. I need to figure out away to pause and resume Azure Synapse Link via automation using Windows PowerShell or some other technology or method.
I can only pause and resume the Synapses Link manually.

You can use Start-AzSynapseLinkConnection PowerShell command to start the Synapse connection link.
After creating the synapse link connection, I have followed the same code from the documentation and here is a sample demo.
Start-AzSynapseLinkConnection -WorkspaceName "rakeshsynapse2" -Name "linkconnection1"

You can get start and get the status of the link connection using the below command.
Get-AzSynapseLinkConnectionDetailedStatus -WorkspaceName "rakeshsynapse2" -Name "linkconnection1"

You can see that the linkconnection was started.
Result:

Linkconnection in Synapse:

Similarly, you can use Stop-AzSynapseLinkConnection PowerShell command to pause the link connection in the synapse.
